# Can 2 Modules Of 2GB Activate Dual-Channel In Windows XP Home 32-bit?

Tags: windows-xp, 32-bit, memory-limit

Windows XP Home is 32-bit and it allows only to use approximately 3.25GB of RAM. If i buy 2 modules of 2GB, will dual-channel still work even though Windows sees only 3.25GB of RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

Dual Channel memory is handled by the memory controller, either in the motherboard chipset for older computers or the processor itself, and so it is not a function of Windows but of the hardware that Windows is running on.